# google calendar new event push notification

Tags: firebase, push-notification, google-calendar-api

I have a custom built `react-native` app, which pulls data from the google calendar API. Is there a way I can send push notifications when an event has been added or changed?

How would I send and receive them?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is nothing built into the Google Calendar **API** to send push notification to devices.

If the user has the Google Calendar **app** installed, it will receive push notifications for reminders that you set for each event. And you can also set a reminder that is sent to the associated email address(es) for the event, which doesn't require the user to have the Google Calendar app installed.

But to receive notification targeted at your custom app, you will have to write a mechanism yourself and call the [Firebase Cloud Messaging API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server).

Comment: Sounds good, I'm a newbie to push notifications, how would I go about it? The google docs are quite terse

Comment: If you search for "how to send push notifications" you are bound to find a lot of good tutorials. If you get stuck implementing one of them, post back with the [minimal code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm using `react-native` can I use javascript, or do I need to use native iOS, android code?

Comment: Sending FCM notifications requires that you have a trusted environment, such as a server you control, or Cloud Functions for Firebase. It can not be securely done from the app itself, which wouldn't solve your problem anyway (since you can't rely on the app being active to send the notification).

Comment: So I deploy a firebase server that listens to google calendar API, and sends push notifications, something like this: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/messaging

Answer (score 0):

Their is a push notification system into the Google Calendar API but I'm not sure it resolves your problem. I think you'll still need some work on your side.

> The Google Calendar API provides push notifications that let you watch
>   for changes to resources. You can use this feature to improve the
>   performance of your application.  It allows you to eliminate the extra
>   network and compute costs involved with polling resources to determine
>   if they have changed. Whenever a watched resource changes, the Google
>   Calendar API notifies your application.

[The Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push)